# "Could not deduce template argument" when template argument is specified

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am attempting to write my own simple reflection system in C++. I have the following test code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <xtr1common>

// common base class
struct TypeDescriptor { };

// specialization for primitive types
template<class T>
struct Primitive : public TypeDescriptor
{
    static Primitive<T> Instance;
};
Primitive<int> Primitive<int>::Instance;

struct ReflectedType
{
    static TypeDescriptor Reflection;
};

// gets an appropriate TypeDescriptor for a type based on whether it has a Reflection member or not.
// if not, then it expects a Primitive<T> specialization
struct DefaultResolver
{
    // used to calculate IsReflected meta-function
    template<class T> static char func(decltype(&T::Reflection));
    template<class T> static int func(...);
    template<class T>
    struct IsReflected
    {
        enum
        {
            value = (sizeof(func<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(char))
        };
    };

    // get the TypeDescriptor for a reflected class
    template<class T, typename std::enable_if<IsReflected<T>::value, int>::value = 0>
    static TypeDescriptor* get()
    {
        return &T::Reflection;
    }

    // get the TypeDescriptor for a Primitive<T> if it is not reflected
    template<class T, typename std::enable_if<!IsReflected<T>::value, int>::value = 0>
    static TypeDescriptor* get()
    {
        return &Primitive<T>::Instance;
    }
};

// helper class that provides type-safe access to a type's TypeDescriptor
template<class T>
struct TypeResolver
{
    static TypeDescriptor* get()
    {
        return DefaultResolver::get<T>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    // no problems here, obviously
    TypeDescriptor* desc = &Primitive<int>::Instance;

    // resolves to false, as expected
    constexpr bool isIntReflected = DefaultResolver::IsReflected<int>::value;

    // resolves to true, as expected
    constexpr bool isClassReflected = DefaultResolver::IsReflected<ReflectedType>::value;

    // this does not compile
    desc = TypeResolver<int>::get();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am running into issues at the `TypeResolver<int>::get()`, with the following errors:

> error C2672: 'DefaultResolver::get': no matching overloaded function found
>   note: while compiling class template member function 'TypeDescriptor *TypeResolver::get(void)'
>   note: see reference to function template instantiation 'TypeDescriptor *TypeResolver::get(void)' being compiled
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation 'TypeResolver' being compiled
>   error C2783: 'TypeDescriptor *DefaultResolver::get(void)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
>   note: see declaration of 'DefaultResolver::get'

I am particularly confused by the second error. I am specifying the template argument, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `std::enable_if` does not have a `::value` member type, only a `::type` member type which is present when the condition is true.
2. In `return DefaultResolver::get<T>()`, providing explicit template arguments disables template argument deduction for those parameters, which what the [`std::enable_if` is depending on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) in order to work.

So first change `::value` in the `std::enable_if` declaractions to `::type`. The next problem would be to allow template argument deduction to work while providing the template type. You can do this by passing a helper template as a function argument, and in the declaration of `DefaultResolver::get()` change your parameters to accept objects of that class type:

```c++
template <class T>
struct type_t { };
// ...
template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<IsReflected<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
static TypeDescriptor* get(type_t<T>);

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<!IsReflected<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
static TypeDescriptor* get(type_t<T>);
// ...
template <class T>
struct TypeResolver
{
  static TypeDescriptor* get()
  {
    return DefaultResolver::get(type_t<T>{});
  }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Turns out this did help, but part 2 was not needed, only part 1. Correcting that fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: @MSinger Out of curiosity what compiler are you using?